# Build empty chart and then set it's data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I have started to implement a column chart at Highcharts.(http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo/ column chart part of it)

I set series as like that:

```
...
series : []
...
```

And I return sth like that from server:

```
[ {
  "name" : "4346",
  "data" : [ 3010840179 ],
  "type" : "column"
}, {
  "name" : "20232",
  "data" : [ 2135308977 ],
  "type" : "column"
} ]
```

When I copy that value and set series at first it renders graphic. However I don't what will return from server(how many elements etc.) and I try that:

```
chart.series = data; //chart is my chart variable's name, data is the returning JSON String from server.
```

However nothing happens at chart, I know it is not a valid usage. What should I do to set series variable of chart at once?

**PS 1:** I try to set data at my callback function at $.getJSON()

**PS 2:** chart.series[n].setData(); is not for me. I have both data and names of every elements from server. I want to set whole series variable of chart at once.

**EDIT 1:** http://jsfiddle.net/HD6CY/ this is what I want to achieve.

**EDIT 3:** I want to create a chart with series : [] and after I get data from server(it takes long time) I want to set it to my chart's seres variable. I don't want to block my chart to be created if waits to get data, I want to build empty and after that I will set it. I will show a loading text at screen so there will be something instead of a null page even it doesn't have anything to show at beginning.

Comment: Look the following demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/ it works.

Comment: You are getting data name by name(i.e., mfst, aapl, goog). However I have all data?

Comment: If you have all `data` with **the exact expected** structure you should pass it directly to `seriesOptions`(used on my example) without process it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check about `addSeries`.

After build an empty chart, do the following.

```
var  variable =   [{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
}, {
    type: 'column',
    name: 'John',
    data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6]
}, {
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [4, 3, 3, 9, 0]
}]; 
for(var i in variable) {
    chart.addSeries(variable[i], false); // don't redraw
}
chart.redraw(); // redraw only after add all series
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HD6CY/4/)

*Reference*

- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#object-Chart

Comment: I do it after my request is complete.

Comment: I show loading icon before I get data because it takes long time. And show an empty chart(I mean a series element with value of []) After I get data I want to set it and hide loading image. I didn't understand why my example doesn't work, there should be a function for it. If I define a function as you said it will block to build an empty chart.

Comment: Here we go! It would be nice if there was a method directly set it but you got the point. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just to highlight, your reference links to HighStock not HighCharts.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried creating your chart on success of your ajax call ? :

```
  ...
  success: function(data) { 
       var chart;  
       chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
             ...
             series: data
             ....
       });
  ...
```

Comment: No, I didn't try it. Should I do it like that?

Comment: It works like that, but how about setting series after getting data?

Comment: maybe you should investigate this function : chart.series[n].setData(); [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ebuTs/16/)

Comment: series has no elements at beginning and I get names from server, it is already coming from server.

Comment: @greg thanks for your help. I have put a link what I want to do.

Comment: @greg: what about showing loading message with `showLoading` and `hideLoading` methods which are available after initializing highcharts?